# Where are generated data binding classes located?

Tags: android, android-databinding

When I build an Android application, the file `R.java` used to reference resources in code is generated at the following location:

> /app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/example/R.java

My understanding is that the new Android data binding library works in a similar way, generating binding classes based on layout filenames during the build process. For example, this layout named `view_drawer_page_header.xml`:

```
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.ViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- actual layout -->

</LinearLayout>
```

should generate a class named `ViewDrawerPageHeaderBinding`. The documentation [mentions](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#custom_binding_class_names) that this class will be located in the `com.example.databinding` package. However, if I search my project for a file with this name after building, I get no results. The app runs fine on devices, so I'm assuming the generated files are part of the final .apk. Is it possible to inspect their contents?

Same question applies to e.g. the generated `BR` class, used to reference updatable `Observable` properties annotated with the `@Bindable` annotation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some more poking, I unearthed the generated files in the following locations:

> /app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/example/databinding/ViewDrawerPageHeaderBinding.java

and

> /app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/example/BR.java

Comment: With Android Studio 3.0 you will find only .class files there. The java files are now at `\MODULE\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\example\PACKAGE`

Comment: In AS Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch 4, you can find it under 
`/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE/databinding/`